# Error at create statement - SQLiteException near "limit"

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a database to use in my Android app.

```
public class DBhelper
    extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBhelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
    }

    public static String create = "Create table " + TBNAME + "(" + ID + " Integer Primary Key Autoincrement," +
        NAME + " text, " +
        TYPE + " text, " +
        LIMIT + " text, " +
        LOCK_TIME + " text);";

    public void details(String name, String limit, String lock_time) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        //everythingz correct!
        db.execSQL("Update " + TBNAME + " set limit='" + limit + "', lock_time='" + lock_time + "' where appname='" + name + "';");
    }
}
```

But I'm getting a syntax error around one of my column names.

```
03-15 17:09:55.636: E/AndroidRuntime(29455): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "limit": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Create table tb1(_id Integer Primary Key Autoincrement,appname text, locktype text, limit text, lock_time text);
03-15 17:09:55.636: E/AndroidRuntime(29455):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
03-15 17:09:55.636: E/AndroidRuntime(29455):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
03-15 17:09:55.636: E/AndroidRuntime(29455):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
03-15 17:09:55.636: E/AndroidRuntime(29455):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
03-15 17:09:55.636: E/AndroidRuntime(29455):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
03-15 17:09:55.636: E/AndroidRuntime(29455):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
```

Comment: limit is an SQLite keyword, so it is making conflict with your column name. Change the name to mylimit, for example and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Looking to your query and your Exception message, "limit" is an `SQLite` keyword used to limit the data amount returned by the SELECT statement. That is why you are getting an Exception. It is making conflict with your column name. Change the column name to mylimit, for example, and it will work.

Comment: I was using private static final String COLUMN_LIMIT = "limit" and that was giving me the error.